# android adapter efficient manipulation of view

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view, android-adapter

Hi I have a custom class extending an ArrayAdapter. I want to be able to change the **ImageButton** background image according to the **List** object data provided in the creation of the adapter. My question is which of the following approach is better.

for example:

**1.** Having a single ImageButton view in the layout and changing the ImageButton in a conditional using ***setBackgroundResource***

> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
>             ....
>
> ```
>     if (myObject.getParent().equalsIgnoreCase("mom")){
>         holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_a);
>     }else if(myObject.getParent().equalsIgnoreCase("dad")){
>         holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_b);
>     }
>       ....
> }
> ```

**2.** Having 2 ImageButton views in the layout and just changing the ***visibility*** of which ImageButton you want to display

> ```
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>      ....
>    if (myObject.getParent().equalsIgnoreCase("mom")){
>       holder.buttonA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>       holder.buttonB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>    }else if(myObject.getParent().equalsIgnoreCase("dad")){
>       holder.buttonB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>       holder.buttonA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>    }
>      ....
> }
> ```

**3.** Having a ***custom*** ImageButton class like this

> ```
> public class CustomButton extends ImageButton {
>   public CustomButton(Context context) {
>       super(context);
>       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>       setForMom();
>   }
>   public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
>           int defStyle) {
>       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>   }
>
>   public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>       super(context, attrs);
>       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
>   }
>   public void setForMom(){
>       setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_a);
>   }
>   public void setForDad(){
>       setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_b);
>   }
>   public void hide() {
>       this.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
>   }
>
> }
> ```

I have read in articles saying the following:

1. the smaller the views the better.  (This could mean go for custom view classes)
2. the image setting inside getView() causes a lot of work for the Android system
3. also there's one that say's always go for custom views because it is better

I have tried all 3, but they still look like they have the same performance. I may have missed something, or is there a better way to do this for better performance?

BTW: I am using https://github.com/huewu/PinterestLikeAdapterView, My app display is like pinterest. It displays images, text, and an ImageButton that I want to change once it is clicked(that is the image button that I want to change the background once clicked).
Also I also am using the view recycling method, I just did not show it here..

Comment: I think this one is good approach for your achievement "Having 2 ImageButton views in the layout and just changing the visibility of which ImageButton you want to display"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the first one is better, but refer to this Amazing [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHTi28zT7rI&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa&index=85) on how to optimaze the listview by 150% and there is another video to optimize it for 175% but you have to understand the first video first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I cannot see here is a `ViewHolder` approach that helps in optimization of memory and reduces lag while scrolling the listview and also increases the **frame rate**.

Also a piece of advice is not to use too many views on screen **[i.e visible/invisible the view is always present in the view hierarchy]** and better use `viewgroup`, as they come into the picture when they are actually required.

Answer (score 0):

Since views in a list view are recycled automatically, you are not able to see the performance difference. That is to say, there are only a few views at any time even if your list is very huge.

The performance for (1) and (3) should be the same. The reason is that you are doing exactly the same thing. Depending on the value of the data, you either set background resource to `a` or `b`. In custom view, you have one extra function call `setForMom/setForDad` (but that shouldn't make a lot of difference) But since background resouce is change everytime a `getView` is called, it may have scrolling performance impact as I have explained later.

(2) has two buttons. This means that creation of every item would mean init two `ImageButtons`.. theoretically this is slower than initializing and drawing just 1 button but since listView recycles views, means only the initial loading will be (slightly/almost negligibly) slower and the scrolling performance will not be affected..

As far as your doubts go:

> the smaller the views the better. (This could mean go for custom view
>   classes)

Smaller views are better.. that is true. Because they can be init and drawn quickly. However this does not mean *go for custom view classes*. Custom views can also be huge, they can have complicated layouts, therefore can be slow.

The reason why people sometimes prefer custom views, is because they want to group certain logic into one class and reuse it at different places. It has nothing to do with : small size view or complex view.

> The image setting inside getView() causes a lot of work for the
>   Android system

This is true (theoretically), though I am not sure if a human can actually feel the performance difference. Therefore, option (2) above is slightly better in terms of theoretical performance.

> There's one that say's always go for custom views because it is better

This is not really correct (in my opinion). Always is a strong word to use. If you just want to display text, or image should you use a custom view? No. My main argument for using a custom view would be:

(1)re-usability So one component can be re-used at multiple places. Lets say I create a custom view that shows a users profile picture and name. I can then use it in different activities and do not have to create it every time from scratch (using `ImageView` and `TextView`).

(2)abstraction. Some logic only specific to a particular view can be grouped inside it.. lets say I want my image to zoom in when i tap on it. I can group this logic within a custom view and create a `TappableImageView` that extends a `ImageView`